# Parsing table nested table within JSON array in android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying get from data of JSON. But I can't. Help me.

I get JSON array from server and parsed JSON objects like following:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> parseAllTable(JSONObject object) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("Value").getJSONArray(1);

            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Iterator<String> iter = jsonObj.keys();
                ArrayList<Object> tmpList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                while(iter.hasNext())
                    tmpList.add(iter.next());
                arrayList.add(tmpList);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("JSONParser => parseAllTable", e.getMessage());
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Like JSON Data:

```
{
  "Successful": true,
  "Value": {
    "CoolerType": [
      {
        "CoolerTypeId": 1,
        "CoolerTypeName": "CVC-360D",
        "description": ""
      },
      {
        "CoolerTypeId": 2,
        "CoolerTypeName": "CVC-360D-2",
        "description": ""
      }
    ],
    "PartsType": [
      {
        "parttypeid": 1,
        "parttypename": "Гэрэл"
      },
      {
        "parttypeid": 2,
        "parttypename": "Гэрэлт самбар"
      }
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what problem getting using current code?

Comment: there is not data. but i checked string. it has in String.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("Value").getJSONArray(1);
```

`Value` is `JSONObject` of JSONArray's instead of `JSONArray`. so get `Value` `JSONObject` from `object` :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONObject("Value").getJSONArray(1);
```